# Single Cron expression to run a scheduled task between 14:30 to 15:30 for every 5 mins on FRI & SAT in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to run a scheduled task between 14:30 to 15:30 for every 5 mins on Friday & Saturday using a single Cron expression in Spring Boot?

If not, what is the best possible way to achieve this with or without Cron in Spring boot 2?

Note: I have already come up with the below approach however it makes two schedulers.

Scheduler 1: `0 30-59/5 14 ? * FRI,SAT *`

Scheduler 2: `0 0-30/5 15 ? * FRI,SAT *`

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Spring 5.3
https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions.

Edited 1: change seconds to 0

```java
@Scheduled("0 30/5 14-15 * * FRI-SAT")
public void run(){
  ...
}
```

Edited 2:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SchedulerConfig {

  private final TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
  private final MyService myService;

  @Bean
  public ApplicationRunner runner() {
    return args -> {
      taskScheduler.schedule(myService::run, new CronTrigger("0 30-59/5 14 ? * FRI,SAT *"));
      taskScheduler.schedule(myService::run, new CronTrigger("0 0-30/5 15 ? * FRI,SAT *"));
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not execute the scheduler from 15:00 to 15:30, instead it will execute from 14:30 to 14:55 & 15:30 to 15:55.

Comment: Have you tried it?
From one of their examples:
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.

Comment: Yea, @Sam Jing Wen! I tried it. In your example above, it uses every 30 mins, so it works. But in my case, it has to be every 5 mins. So, it will go till 15:55.

Comment: I guess you do have to use two cron expressions. Here is a programmatic way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, @Sam Jing Wen. It is a delayed response. However, I ended up using two different cron jobs to achieve the same.